# How to setup child table height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want no gap between `child-table` and `shift-table`. Desire output shown in image below.

`Monday`'s `child-table` will just end before `shift-table`, without any gap in between like `Tuesday`'s tables.

I tried giving `child-table`'s height `100%` but it didn't work. I also tried adding `div` but it just messed my layout.

```css
.parent-table {
  width: 120%;
  /* set the width of the table to 200% */
  table-layout: fixed;
  /* set the table-layout to fixed */
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.child-table {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  /* divide the available width equally among the columns */
}

.shift-table {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
  <table class="clock-card parent-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr> 
        <td style="width: 45px;">
        </td>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let date of dateList; let d = index">
          <td style="vertical-align: top;">
              <table class="hoverable child-table" >
                <tr style="background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);">
                  <th>{{ date | date: 'EE'  }}</th>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);">
                  <td>
                    <span *ngIf="date.getDate() == 1">
                      <strong>{{ date | date: 'MMM' }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    <span [ngClass]="isCurrentDate(date) ? 'current-date' : 'cal-dates'">{{ date | date: 'd' }}</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <ng-container *ngIf="getSample()?.[dateFormt(date)] as attendance">
                 
                  <tr *ngFor="let c of attendance['clock']; let i = index">
                    <th class="Members" id="time" [style.background-color]="i%2 ? 'rgb(250, 209, 209)' : 'rgb(209, 241, 179)'">
                      {{ c.time }}
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </ng-container>           
                <tr>
                  <th>
                    <img src="../assets/plus.png" alt="user" class="profile-pic me-2 " width="20" height="20">
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </table>
          </td>
        </ng-container>  
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table style="width: 45px;text-align: left;">
            <tr *ngFor="let ls of ['SFT', 'BRK', 'OT', 'TWH'];">
              <td><small><strong>{{ls}}</strong></small></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let date of dateList; let d = index">
          <td id='tmpTD' style="vertical-align: top;">
            <ng-container *ngIf="getSample()?.[dateFormt(date)]?.['shift'] as shift">
                <table class="hoverable shift-table">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="Members" style="background-color: rgb(250, 223, 192); display: initial">{{shift}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{shift}}</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </ng-container>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

TS function:

```
  getSample(){
    return {'27/03/2023': {'shift': 'Custom', 'clock': [{'time': '08:02', 'shift': 'Standard', 'updateAt': {'upBy': 'Gate3', 'upOn': '28/03/2023T08:02'}}]}, 
    '28/03/2023': {'shift': 'Custom','clock': [{'time': '08:02', 'shift': 'Standard', 'updateAt': {'upBy': 'Gate3', 'upOn': '28/03/2023T08:02'}}, 
                                               {'time': '10:47', 'shift': 'Standard', 'updateAt': {'upBy': 'Gate2', 'upOn': '28/03/2023T10:47'}}, 
                                               {'time': '10:12', 'shift': 'Standard', 'updateAt': {'upBy': 'Gate3', 'upOn': '28/03/2023T10:12'}}]}}
```

[image]

Comment: Your provided code is not legally formatted, and doesn't produce any visible output at all.  You also haven't included all of your CSS classes.  Please update your post to provide a working example so that we can see the same thing you are seeing, and then we will be happy to help out.

Comment: Assuming those two "Custom" values on the left move up, then presumably the "FT" and "RK" before them should move up as well? But then the two "Custom" on the _right_ won't have those column descriptors(?) any more. Not sure that would make for much of a _logical_ display structure to begin with.

Comment: FYI, you are creating invalid HTML - a `br` can not be a child of `table`.

Comment: Hi @CBroe thank you for your reply, sorry I am beginner in css I need space and br worked so I used it. appreciate if you even suggest any other layout.